# Многоуровневый список с checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, есть многоуровневый список с checkbox -
 [ссылка](https://maxzag.github.io/settings-question.html) .

Задача была в следующем что бы при выборе родителя выбирались все дочерние элементы. А так же что бы при выборе всех дочерних элементов отмечался родительский элемент.
С первый пунктом вопросов не возникло, а вот собственно на втором и остановился.
Бросаю часть кода:

```
        $('.category > input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
        if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
            $(this).next().next('ul').find('input').prop( "checked", true );
        }else{
            $(this).next().next('ul').find('input').prop( "checked", false );
        }
    });
```

Думал может можно как-то проверить количество дочерних элементов и сравнить их с количеством активных элементов и если они равны тогда и активируем родительский элемент, ну не совсем понимаю как это реализовать. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае можно сделать вот так:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    // Находим чекбокс родительской категории
    var categoryInput = $(this).parents('li').eq(1).find('> input[type="checkbox"]');

    // Находим все вложенные инпуты первого уровня
    var inputs = categoryInput.next().next().find('> li > input');

    // Если все вложенные инпуты уже отмечены
    if (inputs.length == inputs.filter(':checked').length) {
        // Изменяем статус флажка и триггерим событие изменния,
        // которое в свою очередь запустит события для родительских категорий
        categoryInput
            .prop('checked', true)
            .trigger('change');
    }
});
```

Comment: Проверил на ссылке заданном в вопросе и все работает.